# ModelBuilder submodel not showing all parameters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I created a master model with many submodels in it. I'm having problems with the last submodel "Table Join Shapefile". In this submodel there are three input parameters: "TDM_Join_INRIX_Merge","TDM_Network_Projection","INRIX_Network_Projection".The input of these parameters have already been existed in the master model. "TDM_Join_INRIX_Merge" is the output of submodel "TDM Data Preparation". "INRIX_Network_Projection" is the output of submodel "INRIX Data Preparation".

So I just need to connect the existing output to the parameters of submodel "Table Join Shapefile". However, after adding the submodel "Table Join Shapefile" into the master model, it only shows two input parameters instead of three. I have to make an independent variable from parameter of "TDM_Network_Projection" instead of connecting the existing "TDM_Network_Projection" (output of submodel "TDM Data Preparation") to it. I couldn't figure out why.

[image: Master Model]

[image: Submodel]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Join requires Table Views to create joins, this is specified in the [syntax](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm#GUID-7AF606B5-7DBF-44B7-A606-7AEDE1BA1FC8) section of the help file. I suspect the output of your sub-model TDM Data Preparation is creating a FeatureClass or Table, not a FeatureLayer or Table View. Insert a Make Table View between the output TDM_Network_Projection and then your sub-model Table Join Shapefile should pick it up.

Comment: You're right! The output TDM_Network_Projection is a feature class but the add join requires a feature layer. I add the Make Feature Layer function and it works. Thank you a lot for your help!